# storing xml strings and variables into files

Tags: c#, xml, string

I have some strings in this format:

```
public static string Script(string user, string password)
{
    return @"<?xml version='1.0'?>" 
            + "<RIBCL VERSION='2.0'>"
            + "<LOGIN USER_LOGIN='" + user + "' PASSWORD='" + password + "'>"
            + "<SERVER_INFO MODE='read'><GET_HOST_DATA /></SERVER_INFO>"
            + "<RIB_INFO MODE='read'><GET_NETWORK_SETTINGS/></RIB_INFO>"
            + "</LOGIN>"
            + "</RIBCL>";
}
```

How can I get the above string variable into an xml file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>"
    <RIBCL VERSION='2.0'>
        <LOGIN USER_LOGIN="user" PASSWORD="password">
            <SERVER_INFO MODE="read">
                <GET_HOST_DATA />
            </SERVER_INFO>"
            <RIB_INFO MODE="read">
                <GET_NETWORK_SETTINGS/>
            </RIB_INFO>
        </LOGIN>
</RIBCL>
```

Where `user` and `password` need to be actual string variables.

Instead of having one different method for every string(quite a few) can I somehow store each into their own file? The only thing would be the `user` and `password` variables which would need to get added everytime so not sure how to handle that part.

Comment: try your code with password = `123/>456`

Comment: works fine. as that input goes into a textbox and then it gets written to a stream.

Comment: Then try to open the resulting XML.

Comment: @I4V: a better example would be `123<456`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to store your string like string format template

For example, like:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<RIBCL VERSION='2.0'>
    <LOGIN USER_LOGIN='{0}' PASSWORD='{1}'>
        <SERVER_INFO MODE='read'><GET_HOST_DATA /></SERVER_INFO>
        <RIB_INFO MODE='read'><GET_NETWORK_SETTINGS/></RIB_INFO>
    </LOGIN>
</RIBCL>
```

Your script method should load particular string from somewhere, and after that just should apply `String.Format`:

```
return String.Format(data, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(user), HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(password));
```

It will work if each of your strings has only `user` and `password` fields, which should be set.

Comment: HTML encoding is different from XML encoding. This is another case of  building XML through string manipulation, and has the same problems. As another user commented earlier, try this with password = `123/>456`.

Comment: It does work just fine using this: `XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("Get_ILO_Details.xml");

            string finalScript =  String.Format(doc.InnerXml, txtILOUserName.Text, txtILOPassword.Text);`

Comment: The resulting XML includes `<LOGIN USER_LOGIN="user" PASSWORD="123<456">` which is not "ok".

Comment: After `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` result will contains `<LOGIN USER_LOGIN="123&lt;/456" PASSWORD="123/&gt;456">`

Answer (score 1):

First, never build XML using string manipulation. The rules are different. For instance, what if `password` had a character in it that was invalid for an xml attribute?

Second, I would recommend building your XML using LINQ to XML. No file I/O that way.

Comment: I'm not really saving anything to a file yet. That string is then sent to an interface on another machine using .net POST which listens for that type of formata and sends back a response.

Comment: You asked about _reading_ the XML from a file. I'm saying that if you build the XML using LINQ to XML, then you won't have to deal with files.

Answer (score 0):

I have had to create a similar application to be called from ASP.NET. The solution I found the best was to create the xml file in resources folder and just update the USER_LOGIN and PASSWORD attributes.

One other point to note is that you need to remove the xml declation from the top when sending to HPILO as it does not recognise it. The file should start with

```
<RIBCL VERSION=2.0>
```

Comment: That only works for ilo3 or 4, 2 requires it. But having it there for 3 and 4 still runs the scripts so it's fine